# I want to extract only json. Help regex. dev environment is javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to extract only json. Help regex. dev environment is javascript
https://regex101.com/ from that site
I did it with PCRE (PHP), but I need a regular expression for JAVACRIPT.
PCRE (PHP) : {(?:[^{}]|(?R))*}

```
Connecting to server...
Sending transaction...
Transaction:
    {
        "time": "13",
        "expiration": "12312",
        "abc": 1,
        "bbb": 1000000,
        "delay": "0",
        "chainId": 1024,
        "actions": [
            {
                "contract": "asd",
                "actionName": "asd",
                "data": "[\"asd\",\"asd\",\"asd\",\"1\",\"\"]"
            }
        ],
    }

    Transaction has been sent.
    Transaction receipt:
    {
        "brainUsage": {
        },
        "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "",
        "returns": [
            "[]"
        ],
    }
    
    SUCCESS! Transaction has been irreversible
    Transaction receipt:
    {
        "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "",
        "returns": [
            "[]"
        ],
        "receipts": [
            {
                "funcName": "sd.asda/asd",
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You've asked this same question only a few minutes ago. Stop that

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not offer recursive regular expressions like PCRE does. So, if you are dead set on using RegExp, your best bet will be a two-step process:

1. Use markers other than `{` or `}` with a global RegExp:

Example:

```js
let results = text.match(/(?:Transaction|receipt):\s+\{[\s\S]+?\}\s+(?:Transaction|SUCCESS!)/g);
```

Here the "markers" are `Transaction:` and `receipt:` for the start of a block and `Transaction` or `SUCCESS!` for the end.
We need to match non-greedy (`+?`) inside the JSON block to limit each match to a single block of JSON.
`[\s\S]` is used to match any character including line terminators. `.` does not match line terminators.

2. Extract JSON from each result of step #1:

```js
let results[0].match(/\{[\s\S]+\}/);
```

Here we match greedily (`+`) to get the whole block.

However, this approach heavily depends on the reliability of the text to be parsed. If the wording or order changes, the above code will likely fail.

A more robust approach, but without regular expressions, would be to parse the text properly.

Pseudo code (untested):

```
blocks = []
block = ""
level = 0
for each char:
  if char == '{':
    level++
  
  if level > 0:
    block += char

    if char == '}':
      level--

      if level == 0:
        blocks.append(block)
        block = ""
```

While this approach will work regardless of the format around the JSON blocks, it will catch invalid blocks as well, e.g. `Hello {world}` will return a block of `{world}`. However, properly parsing each block afterwards with `JSON.parse` will find the correct ones.